Facing issue while migrating Jest@26 to Jest@27
I'm trying to migrate Jest from version 26 to 27 in my Next.js 13 project but facing the following error while running test after updating to Jest 27 version -
 FAIL  src/__tests__/app.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot combine importAssertions and importAttributes plugins.

      at validatePlugins (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/plugin-utils.ts:130:11)
      at getParser (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/index.ts:106:5)
      at parse (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/index.ts:32:22)
      at parser (node_modules/@babel/core/src/parser/index.ts:28:19)
          at parser.next (<anonymous>)
      at normalizeFile (node_modules/@babel/core/src/transformation/normalize-file.ts:51:24)
          at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
      at run (node_modules/@babel/core/src/transformation/index.ts:38:36)
          at run.next (<anonymous>)
      at transform (node_modules/@babel/core/src/transform.ts:29:20)
          at transform.next (<anonymous>)
      at evaluateSync (node_modules/gensync/index.js:251:28)
      at fn (node_modules/gensync/index.js:89:14)
      at stopHiding - secret - don't use this - v1 (node_modules/@babel/core/src/errors/rewrite-stack-trace.ts:97:14)
      at transformSync (node_modules/@babel/core/src/transform.ts:66:52)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:320:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.683 s

before updating the Jest, the test was passing so it's not related to my code.
My jest.config.js looks like this -
module.exports = {
  collectCoverage: true,
  coverageProvider: 'babel',
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    '**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}',
    '!**/*.d.ts',
    '!**/node_modules/**',
    '!<rootDir>/out/**',
    '!<rootDir>/.next/**',
    '!<rootDir>/*.config.js',
    '!<rootDir>/coverage/**',
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
 
    '^.+\\.(css|sass|scss)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js',
 
    '^.+\\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|avif|ico|bmp|svg)$/i': `<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js`,
 
    '^@/components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/components/$1',
 
    '@next/font/(.*)': `<rootDir>/__mocks__/nextFontMock.js`,
    'next/font/(.*)': `<rootDir>/__mocks__/nextFontMock.js`,
    'server-only': `<rootDir>/__mocks__/empty.js`,
  },
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/.next/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    // Use babel-jest to transpile tests with the next/babel preset
    // https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transform-objectstring-pathtotransformer--pathtotransformer-object
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': ['babel-jest', { presets: ['next/babel'] }],
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    '^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$',
  ],
}

and babel.config.js -
module.exports = {
  presets: ["next/babel"],
  plugins: [
    [
      'react-css-modules',
      {
        autoResolveMultipleImports: true,
        generateScopedName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]',
        handleMissingStyleName: 'throw',
        webpackHotModuleReloading: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
};

my package.json snapshot is here:
 {
    "dependencies": {
    "abortcontroller-polyfill": "^1.7.5",
    "babel-plugin-react-css-modules": "^5.2.6",
    "next": "13.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^10.4.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "jest": "27.0.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0"
  }
}

Please help me resolve this !

For me, this error was due to the fact that we were using next/babel in our babel config for jest tests and nextjs 14 uses @babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions while jest uses the plugin "babel-preset-current-node-syntax": "1.1.0" which uses @babel/plugin-syntax-import-assertions.
Import assertions have been proposed to be replaced by import attributes which is more flexible: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-import-attributes
However, you can get the old + the new syntax with https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-syntax-import-attributes#deprecatedassertsyntax
Nextjs 14 uses import assertions, which is a problem when we use the next/babel preset in babel.config.js and jest-babel is applied on top of that, applying import attributes via the dependency module "babel-preset-current-node-syntax": "1.1.0".
However, the use of import assertions was replaced with babel-plugin-syntax-import-attributes with deprecatedassertsyntax and merged into next canary: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/65749
Finally, the resolutions property in the yarn's package.json did not affect the installed @jest/core/node_modules/babel-preset-current-node-syntax version.
Thus we did this:
yarn install babel-preset-current-node-syntax@1.0.0
Remove the caret operator, so it's pinned like so:
"babel-preset-current-node-syntax": "1.0.0",
Then, we did this:

import { exec } from '@utils/scripting';
import { existsSync } from 'node:fs';

const JEST_BABEL_PRESET_CURRENT_NODE_SYNTAX_LOC = 'node_modules/@jest/core/node_modules/babel-preset-current-node-syntax';
const VERSION_ONE_BABEL_PRESET_CURRENT_NODE_SYNTAX_LOC = 'node_modules/babel-preset-current-node-syntax';
export const run = (): void => {
  if (!existsSync(`${process.cwd()}/${JEST_BABEL_PRESET_CURRENT_NODE_SYNTAX_LOC}`)) {
    throw new Error(`The file ${JEST_BABEL_PRESET_CURRENT_NODE_SYNTAX_LOC} does not exist.
        You probably upgraded jest and now you have to downgrade or read the comments in deploy/bin/patch-jest-import-assertions.ts`);
  }
  exec(`rm -rf ${JEST_BABEL_PRESET_CURRENT_NODE_SYNTAX_LOC}`);
  exec(`cp -R ${VERSION_ONE_BABEL_PRESET_CURRENT_NODE_SYNTAX_LOC} ${JEST_BABEL_PRESET_CURRENT_NODE_SYNTAX_LOC}`);
};

Now, next/babel will be in charge of adding either import attributes or import assertions, and we don't use either syntax so we don't care.

For us next.js app, this was the solution:
babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
  plugins: ['@emotion/babel-plugin'],
};

And install this as dev dependency:
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react

